# SharePoint Online Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, power-automate, flow

Can a SharePoint online List have more than one workflow associated with it, or is it limited to just one?

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one workflows (designer workflows 2013 as well as Power automate flows) associated with single list in SharePoint online site.

---

**Note**: SharePoint designer 2010 workflows have been retired since August 1, 2020 for new tenants and removed from existing tenants on November 1, 2020.

After August 1, 2020, new Microsoft 365 customers can use SharePoint 2013 workflows or Power Automate. However, SharePoint 2013 workflows will follow a similar retirement path in the future, so it's **highly recommended to use Power Automate** or other supported solutions (Nintex, K2 etc.). You won't lose any content during the transition. However, all migration of workflows is a manual process.

**Documentation**: [SharePoint 2010 workflow retirement](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-2010-workflow-retirement-1ca3fff8-9985-410a-85aa-8120f626965f)

Comment: Hi @David, does this help you? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.